What is the input for Mule Oracle EBS Connector "Invoke PL/SQL REST Service" operation?
I'm trying to connect to Oracle EBS through mulesoft provided Oracle EBS connector 12.2.
In that I want to use "Invoke PL/SQL REST Service" module of EBS Connector.
I'm not sure what needs to be sent to this node to fetch data from Oracle EBS.
Can someone please help me with an example?

[edit] your question to add a [mre].

Also have you read the documentation?

Title doesn't reflect the question please edit.

Fixed the title for you.
